# Acessar objetos de JFrames Diferentes(JAVA)

Tags: java, netbeans, herança, getters-setters

Boa tarde, Alguém pode me ajudar com um projeto?

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema simples de vacinas,

mas estou com muita dificuldade para acessar atributos entre um JFrame e outro uma vez que em cada JFrame tenho que instanciar um objeto como new...

por exemplo tenho 2 jframes, faço o cadastro dos dados de um usuario em um, e preciso resgatar esses dados tanto para logar, quanto para acessar o painel do usuário...

por exemplo: JFrame1.java:

```
Cadastro cadastro = new cadastro();
cadastro.CadastrarUsuario(txtNome.getText(), txtSenha.getText());
```

ai a classe cadastro receberá os dados através da instância "cadastro", com os dados que foram passados para o método "CadastrarUsuario" usando o getNome() e getSenha em um outro JFrame, mas como vou acessar essa instância em outro JFrame para resgatar os mesmos dados? algo do tipo:
JFrame2.java:

```
Cadastro cadastro;    
cadastro.Login(getNome(), getSenha());
```

se eu criar uma nova instância para o objeto cadastro no JFrame2 não consigo acessar os dados originalmente inseridos no JFrame1...

se alguém tiver disponibilidade para me ajudar agradeceria muito...

OBS: não posso usar Banco de dados nessa aplicação, por isso preciso dos dados armazenados em tempo de execução.

Answer (score 0):

Perdoe-me se entendi errado sua pergunta, mas para pegar atributos de um JFrame1 inicial em outro JFrame2, você deve passar a instancia atual do JFrame1 como parâmetro no construtor do JFrame2, alegando que o JFrame1 tenha métodos públicos que retorne os dados do seu JTextField. Exemplo:

Frame/Classe principal:

```
public class Frame1 {        
   public String getTxtNome(){
      return this.txtNome.getText();
   }
   public String getTxtSenha(){
      return this.txtSenha.getText();
   }
   //Em qualquer lugar do seu código que chame o Frame2, que irá receber os dados:
   Frame2 frame2 = new Frame2(this);
}
```

Frame/Classe que receberá os dados:

```
public class Frame2 {

   private final Frame1 mainFrame;   

   public Frame2(Frame1 frame){
      this.mainFrame = frame;
   }

}
```

A partir disso, você poderá acessar os métodos criado no Frame1 através do objeto "mainFrame" criado no Frame2.

Answer (score 0):

Veja. Se não me falha a memória uma aplicação Swing só pode ter um JFrame, porém mais de um JDialog, que podem ser instanciados para aparecer na frente do JFrame mas somente depois do JFrame já ter sido criado. O JFrame seria a sua janela principal, e caso você queira antes disso preencher um cadastro precisa respeitar a ordem que é primeiro instanciar o JFrame e logo em seguida instanciar e tornar visível um JDialog de cadastro.

Repare que, quando aparece o JDialog, para não deixar o usuário voltar para o JFrame sem antes fechar o JDialog este deve ter sido instanciado como modal.

[Esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4089311/2241463) no SOen informa como fazer para passar dados de um para o outro. Basicamente você deve construir a API do sua classe JDialog de forma a poder pedir a ela, a partir do JFrame, os dados que foram preenchidos pelo usuário no JDialog. Basicamente, criar getters no JDialog e chamá-los a partir do JFrame.